# yarn install: Listing the refs for ... failed / Exit code: 128

Tags: github, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

So i cloned an older git repo to my new device and simply ran "yarn install" in the projects root directory. It gave me this output (i use yarn v2 cli / berry):

> (node:52346) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
> mux-demux@git://github.com/Raynos/mux-demux.git#error-messages:
> Listing the refs for git://github.com/Raynos/mux-demux.git failed at
> ChildProcess.u.on
> (/Users/linus/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js:2:412797)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13) at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:982:16) at Socket.stream.socket.on
> (internal/child_process.js:389:11) at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
> at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12) (node:52346)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:52346) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> (node:52346)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
> sockjs-client@git://github.com/substack/sockjs-client.git#browserify-npm:
> Listing the refs for git://github.com/substack/sockjs-client.git
> failed at ChildProcess.u.on
> (/Users/linus/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js:2:412797)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13) at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:982:16) at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
> (node:52346) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

yarnpkg (v1) gives me:

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/substack/sockjs-client.git
Directory: /Users/linuxgrolmes/PhpStormProjects/ifs-user-online-list-vue2
Output:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Operation timed out
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

By the way, the librarys "mux-demux" and "sockjs-client" are the only ones which links are referenced with "git://" instead of "https://" at the beginning in "package-lock.json".

Could it be this is a cause of the problem? I tried a lot up to this point and I'm not really sure on how to continue now..

Comment: GitHub stopped supporting `git://` in March: https://blog.readthedocs.com/github-git-protocol-deprecation/

Comment: oh i see! Can you tell me how to fix this? I already tried replacing `git://` with `https://` in package-lock.json, but this didn't work. When I delete this file and yarn.lock it doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm not a "yarn guy" but switching to `https://` is the correct fix as far as using GitHub goes. What *else* you might have to do, I don't know.